# What to use in the repositories of the MVVM pattern in android?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I am currently working in the android app where I am using a MVVM architecture
so I came across a post where in they mentioned while using MVVM, one should not use LiveData(Lifecycle aware components) in repositories but I didn't understand the explanation why.
Here is the link to the post: [enter link description here](https://proandroiddev.com/dont-use-livedata-in-repositories-f3bebe502ed3)

In this he mentioned about Flow but i didn't understand that part as well any video explanation would be helpful

Can some one please tell me the actual reason and implementation in simple words?

Comment: One issue it mentioned is that `LiveData` is running on the UI thread. Other than that you may forget about Flow for now, and just try to think about if you have to use LiveData and it is running on the UI thread, how you would handle this situation, and would this cause any issues to your project.

Comment: Let's take an example of login live data in repo. It will remain active as long as i am in login activity right? if I leave that activity then that live data observer will be cancelled. So there will be no issues

Comment: @RyanWong this is kinda false info, you can use `liveData { withContext(IO) { emit` and then suddenly liveData will be "running on the background thread"

Comment: @epicpandaforce that is the point. If the author claims not to use LiveData because it is running on the UI thread, and we have a way not to have that run on the UI thread, then the rest of the article is not something we should worry about. I would feel that was written to promote Flow but probably it is out of the discussion scope here.

Comment: Especially if I just generally say, you probably don't need "repository" at all, just use a usecase or something